# Is a blank paper page on passport normal?

Tags: passports, french-citizens

I recieved my French passport earlier, but after strolling through it I found that there has been a paper page (classic plain paper, not visa page paper) inserted near the end of it.

It is attached as usual and has the passport number embossed, with dots (like on every visa page), into it so it has evidence that it hasn't been added after fabrication.

Could it be a problem that would need a full reissuing (I hope not) or can it be used as normal?

Comment: I remember having had one of those in a previous passport, but the stitching of the page was quite obviously different. I believe it was intended to be removed before being delivered but was forgotten. Don’t remember having her had an issue with it, though it was a  very long while ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to gently pull it off, and it came off without any trace

So I can bet on a fabrication glitch (due to the fact that it has the passport number printed on it), and I am happy to not have to reissue the passport